# What happened to the SPADE pirate members after Ace's death?

Tags: one-piece

Ace formed his pirate crew named "SPADE" pirates after leaving his hometown.

[image]

[image: 100th Fight]

After having a continuous clash between Ace and Whitebeard, Ace understood the feelings of Edward Newgate toward his crew and how he considers them as his own family.  He also tells them if he joins, they will accept Ace as his family in his crew.  He, along with his former crewmates, abandoned SPADE pirates.  Afterward, all SPADE pirates had disbanded in different Whitebeard divisions. After Ace's death, they didn't appear in anime or manga.

What happened afterward?

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that are went in different ways, just like rest of white beard pirates.

One other theory is that, when Luffy has to fight black-beard then white-beard pirates(+ spade pirated + ...all) may join him for severals reasons

1. Luffy is Ace's brother
2. Luffy stood upto Whitebeard and won his respect.
3. To payback to black-beard for the death of Ace & White-beard!
4. Black-beard is just mean..
5. Luffy is luffy (you have your freedom yet you are part of a big/power crew)